# mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN4YAML6detail9node_data12empty_scalarB5cxx11

Tags: linux, mongodb, upgrade, archlinux

I am having trouble with the MongoDB install on my Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux.
I'd updated it without thinking about it, and apparently I needed to notify Mongo that I wanted the database files to be upgraded as well. But I didn't do this, otherwise I wouldn't have been here.
So I checked [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#upgrade-procedures) and did some googling and found that I needed to downgrade to 3.6, input the correct setting and upgrade.
The only problem is that Arch is a rolling distro, meaning it's constantly upgrading and can be kind of a pain to downgrade. Luckily I found [this website](http://tardis.tiny-vps.com/aarm/packages/) where I can get all the packages I want.
Using this I downgraded MongoDB and in turn I had to downgrade boost-libs, wiredtiger and yaml-cpp. This resulted in ldd /usr/bin/mongod looking like this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff988f3000)
libwiredtiger-3.0.0.so => /usr/lib/libwiredtiger-3.0.0.so 
(0x0000ffff95ddc000)
libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.3 (0x0000ffff95dae000)
libstemmer.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstemmer.so.0 (0x0000ffff95d3e000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x0000ffff95d17000)
libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1 (0x0000ffff95cfe000)
libyaml-cpp.so.0.5 => /usr/lib/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5     (0x0000ffff95c76000)
libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x0000ffff95c04000)
libpcrecpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0x0000ffff95bea000)
libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 (0x0000ffff95b4d000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1 =>    /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1 (0x0000ffff95b1f000)
libboost_system.so.1.65.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.65.1 (0x0000ffff95b0a000)
libboost_iostreams.so.1.65.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.65.1 (0x0000ffff95ad9000)
libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000ffff95ab2000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x0000ffff95a0e000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x0000ffff95747000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x0000ffff9572f000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffff9571a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff9556e000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff954ab000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff95486000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff95457000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff952e1000)
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 => /usr/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1     (0x0000ffff988c5000)
libtcmalloc.so.4 => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4 (0x0000ffff950d7000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/liblz4.so.1 (0x0000ffff950ac000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x0000ffff9508b000)
liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x0000ffff95057000)
libunwind.so.8 => /usr/lib/libunwind.so.8 (0x0000ffff95005000)
```

But now when I run mongod, it just says

```
mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN4YAML6detail9node_data12empty_scalarB5cxx11E
```

I've tried googling for node data empty scalar but I'm not getting any results or really know what it means, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Also, my question was already on serverfault, but there it was put on hold. So I'm hoping this is the correct place to ask it.

Comment: `echo _ZN4YAML6detail9node_data12empty_scalarB5cxx11 | c++filt` should give you a friendlier name. Because the name include `node` I would not be surprised if it was part of a list or a tree. I tested on Fedora 28, Ubuntu 18 and CetOS 7 but it could not be unmangled. It looks like you will need to unmangle it on your machine.

Comment: @jww I did that and it resulted in `yaml::detail::node_data::empty_Scalar[abi:cxx11]` which led to me googling some more and I think I'm going to have to compile MongoDB myself and include the yaml library and hope that it's going to work then.

Comment: Be sure to use the same compiler and compiler options when building things. C++ programs are sensitive to both. You should probably build MongoDB and its dependent libraries as a group and just use `rpath's` to ensure the correct runtime linking.

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by downgrading the `yaml-cpp` package on archlinux back to the version which you installed when you compiled mongodb

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've stopped using mongodb almost a year ago.

Comment: @TheDutchman SO shouldn't be a personal helpdesk but a knowledge base. That means you can still verify my answer is correct so it might help someone else

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I verify if it's correct if I don't have mongodb installed anymore. Also I think I may have downgraded yaml-cpp back then and it didn't help, I'm not sure though.

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the issue on my system

Comment: Save my day! Thanks, @Sjon